# Have to write a Tic Tac Toe game for 2 players

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gameBoard 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String str1;
    Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1 please enter 1 or 2, 1 = O, 2 = X");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    if(a == 1){
        String str2 = "O";
        str1 = str2;
    }else{
        String str2 = "X";
        str1 = str2;
    }
    System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the ROW (1, 2 or 3) you want: ");
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    if (b == 1 || b == 2 || b == 3){
        System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the COLUMN you want: ");
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        if( c == 1 || c == 2 || c == 3){
            if ( b == 2 && c == 2){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   | " + str1 + " |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
            }
            if (b == 1 && c == 1){
                System.out.println(str1 + " |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("  |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("  |   |   ");
            }
            if (b == 2 && c == 1){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println(str1 + "  |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
            }
            if (b == 3 && c == 1){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println(str1 + "   |   |   ");
            }
            if (b == 1 && c == 2){
                System.out.println("   | " +str1 +  " |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
            }
            if( b == 3 && c == 2){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   | " + str1 + "|   ");
            }
            if (b == 1 && c == 3){
                System.out.println("   |   |" + str1);
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
            }
            if (b == 2 && c == 3){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |  | " + str1);
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
            }
            if ( b == 3 && c == 3){
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                System.out.println("-----------");
                System.out.println("   |   | " + str1);
            }
            System.out.println("Player 2 please enter 1 or 2, 1 = O, 2 = X");
            int e = scan.nextInt();
            if(e == 1){
                String str2 = "O";
                str1 = str2;
            }else{
                String str2 = "X";
                str1 = str2;
        }
        System.out.println("Player 2 please enter the ROW (1, 2 or 3) you want: ");
        int f = scan.nextInt();
        if (f == 1 || f == 2 || f == 3){
            System.out.println("Player 2 please enter the COLUMN you want: ");
            int g = scan.nextInt();
            if( g == 1 || g == 2 || g == 3){
                if ( f == 2 && g == 2){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   | " + str1 + " |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                }
                if (f == 1 && g == 1){
                    System.out.println(str1 + " |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("  |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("  |   |   ");
                }
                if (f == 2 && g == 1){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println(str1 + "  |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                }
                if (f == 3 && g == 1){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println(str1 + "   |   |   ");
                }
                if (f == 1 && g == 2){
                    System.out.println("   | " +str1 +  " |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                }
                if( f == 3 && g == 2){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   | " + str1 + "|   ");
                }
                if (f == 1 && g == 3){
                    System.out.println("   |   |" + str1);
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |  |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                }
                if (f == 2 && g == 3){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |  | " + str1);
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                }
                if ( f == 3 && g == 3){
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   |   ");
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                    System.out.println("   |   | " + str1);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

    }



}

}
}
}
```

I'm writing this thing entirely with if statements right now and I feel like this is an inherently wrong approach to this task. I can get the first move of each player but I cannot figure out a way to "save" the state the board is in after the first player moves, its just prints a board with player 1's first move, then prints a board with player 2's first move, but they are not on the same board together. I feel a bit out of my league here...

Comment: You want the board to be presented by an Array<String>(3,3). Then you store "X" and "O" in the Array, and output the Array. To check if someone has won is a bit more trick (check horizontally, vertically and diagonally). Yes, what you've done so far is wrong.

Comment: This is very much a procedural approach.  YOu want an object oriented approach.  Make the board an object, give it some methods that do things like print the state and update a square with an X or O, then have a playing method that has a while loop that runs until the game ends

Comment: Try using loop statements. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @jedison A good point about using a two-dimensional array, though there is no `Array` in Java.

Comment: When you tend to see a pattern of duplication, it's a good hint that something different can be done.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming

Answer (score 1):

You should be more inclined to use fields (for "saving") and methods (for re-using bits of code)

Try this example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoard {
    // Use a matrix to emulate a 3*3 grid.
    private String[][] board = new String[3][3];
    private String[][] players = { { "Player 1", "X" }, { "Player 2", "O" } };
    private int currentPlayer = -1;

    public boolean isBoardFull() {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String col : row) {
                if (col == null) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean gameIsWon() {
        // I shall leave this to your imagination ;)
        return false;
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String col : row) {
                System.out.print("|" + (col == null ? " " : col) + "|");
            }

            System.out.println("\n---------");
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        // Try-with-resource (Java 7+)

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (!isBoardFull()) {
                currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2;

                boolean valid = false;

                // Loop until a certain player makes a valid move
                while (!valid) {
                    System.out.print(players[currentPlayer][0] + ", choose your row: \n> ");
                    int row = scanner.nextInt() - 1;

                    System.out.print(players[currentPlayer][0] + ", you have chosen row " + (row + 1) + ". Choose your column: \n> ");
                    int col = scanner.nextInt() - 1;

                    if (board[row][col] == null) {
                        board[row][col] = players[currentPlayer][1];

                        printBoard();

                        if (gameIsWon()) {
                            System.out.println(players[currentPlayer][0] + " wins!");

                            return;
                        }

                        valid = true; // This will allow players to switch turns
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This slot is taken, try again!");
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameBoard().play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new class from yours, this one will save elements from user input, just complete it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gameBoard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1, j, i, b;
        char str1 = 'o';
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] g = new char[3][3];
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
                if(j == 2){
                    System.out.print(n);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(n + " | ");
                }
                g[i][j] = ' ';
                n++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        n = 1;
        System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the square you want (1-9): ");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        while(b > 9 || b < 1){
            System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the square you want (1-9): ");
            b = scan.nextInt();
        }
        switch(b){
            case 1:
                if(g[0][0] == ' '){
                    g[0][0] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(g[0][1] == ' '){
                    g[0][1] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(g[0][2] == ' '){
                    g[0][2] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(g[1][0] == ' '){
                    g[1][0] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if(g[1][1] == ' '){
                    g[1][1] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if(g[1][2] == ' '){
                    g[1][2] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if(g[2][0] == ' '){
                    g[2][0] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                if(g[2][1] == ' '){
                    g[2][1] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                if(g[2][2] == ' '){
                    g[2][2] = str1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Already played on that square");
                }
                break;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j ++){
                if(j == 2){
                    System.out.print(g[i][j]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(g[i][j] + " | ");
                }
                n++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }    
        System.out.print("Bye");                
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you giving an idea on how to finish it :)

Good luck

Btw here you have a [Tic Tac Toe](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~sbrandt/13H/java/TicTacToe.java) example, you can guide yourself from there. And [here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/tic-tac-toe-version-3-console-based.html) you have another one. Just in case you're stuck in something